# Loading Json data won't show

Tags: java, android, xml, multithreading

I am trying to make an app that takes data from google sheet in JSON format.
I have tried a couple of different codes to make the data simply apeare on the screen, but could not make this happen.
would be glad for ideas.

- tried with a several codes using AsyncTask and saw it is not working. so tried a

different approach..

the following app is a blank page with a button, that when you click it , it suppose to make name list apear on the screen.

**the JSON url:**
https://myjson.dit.upm.es/api/bins/1anx

**the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="click me!"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="150dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:text="list"/>


    </ScrollView>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/userList"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The ActivityMain.Java :**

```
 package com.example.webdownload;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.webdownload.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ActivityMainBinding binding;
     ArrayList<String> userList;
     ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
     Handler mainHandler= new Handler();
     ProgressDialog progressDialog;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
         setContentView(binding.getRoot());
         initializeUserList();
         binding.data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 new fetchData().start();

             }
         });



     }

     private void initializeUserList() {

         userList = new ArrayList<>();
         listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userList);
         binding.userList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
     }

     class fetchData extends  Thread{

        String data = "";
         @Override
         public void run() {
             mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                     progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data");
                     progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                     progressDialog.show();
                 }
             });


             try {
                 URL url =new URL("http://myjson.dit.upm.es/api/bins/1anx");
                 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                 String line;
                 while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                     data = data + line;
                 }
                 if(!data.isEmpty()){
                     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                     JSONArray users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Users");
                    userList.clear();
                     for(int i =0;i<users.length();i++){
                         JSONObject names = users.getJSONObject(i);
                         String name = names.getString("name");
                         userList.add(name);
                     }
                 }
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                     listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
             });

         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: i think you need `listAdapter.items = userList` or something similar, before your `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. side note, whatever tutorial(s) you're following seems to be quite outdated

Comment: tried the listAdapter addition, did not work..  it won't even show the progression dialog. and about the tutorials - you are right. couldn't find new ones about the topic unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

**I Think This is happening because your JSON URL have some spelling mistake**

[image]

**The spelling of name (*namr*) is wrong**

> You can check your json url - [Your wrong json url](https://myjson.dit.upm.es/api/bins/1anx)